# How does distributed checksum works?

Tags: text-processing

I am looking for information as to how distributed checksum applications like Vipul's razor, Pyzor or DCC works? I have a similar requirement where I can use such a distributed checksum feature in my program.

So I am looking for some documentation explaining the algorithms behind distributed checksums.

with regards,

raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyzor is an implementation of "hash sharing". Quote from [SpamAssassin's Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/HashSharingSystem):

> One of the approaches used to identify spam goes like this; if I see a spam message at 8:30 in the morning, I send a checksum of that message to an online database of spam. When you get that message a little later on in the morning, your mail system asks that online database, "Has anyone reported this as spam?". The online database can report back "yes", allowing your mail system to raise the spam score for that message.

Depending on what you're trying to do with distributed hashes, DHTs ([Distributed hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)) might also be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks, What I am really looking for is a nut and blot doc so I can understand what really goes on under the hood.